# How to remove uppercase URL's with octopress Heroku blog?

Tags: heroku, jekyll, octopress

I am converting my blog to octopress/jekyll hosted on Heroku.

It all works well locally however when loaded up to Heroku I get capitalised URL's that seem to persist across updates and rebuilds of the remote repository.

The posts at locations like mydomain/category/postname contain html redirection files to help with the change in url structure between the previous wordpress domain/category/postname to the default octopress style domain/yyyy/mm/dd/postname. These are created using the [Alias Generator plugin from tsmango](https://github.com/tsmango/jekyll_alias_generator)

If I type http://www.williampickup.org/Ceramics/john-dermer into a browser the redirect works, while the lowercase version doesn't. The uppper case directory names for categories were an artefact of the original script I used to create the Alias yaml entries in my blog posts. I have fixed that locally however I can't seem to upload the correct lowercase directory structure to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I noticed that the directory names were being capitalised when I committed the changes to my git repository.
The solution turned out to be to change the git config setting so that ignorecase = true.